# how to get socket.id of a connection on client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Im using the following code in index.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
console.log(socket.id);
});
```

the above code lets me print the socket.id in console.

But when i try to print the socket.id on client side using the following code

```
<script>
var socket = io();
var id = socket.io.engine.id;
document.write(id);
</script>
```

it gives 'null' as output in the browser.

Comment: What do the **[docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket)** say about getting the socket id? Have you tried anything else?

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr.Meeseeks Found it on docs. socket.id can be obtained after 'connect' event.

Comment: Note, the `socket.id` on the server is not made available to the client, so if you want the id from the server, then you can send it to the client yourself in a message.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should wait for the event `connect` before accessing the `id` field:

With this parameter, you will access the sessionID

```
socket.id
```

Edit with:

**Client-side:**

```
var socketConnection = io.connect();
socketConnection.on('connect', function() {
  const sessionID = socketConnection.socket.sessionid; //
  ...
});
```

**Server-side:**

```
io.sockets.on('connect', function(socket) {
  const sessionID = socket.id;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hi, This id getting different while connecting socket

Comment: I see, this is your session ID, each time you connect you get a different one

Comment: Yes, every time while connecting the socket we get different session I'd.It means this is session id.Now,how to fetch socket id ? Which will remain same for particular device?

Comment: This is another question that you might create a new one, specifying the issue that you are facing and the code that you tried, I might jump in and try to help for sure :)

Answer (score 13):

**For Socket 2.0.4 users**

**Client Side**

```
 let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:<portNumber>'); 
 console.log(socket.id); // undefined
 socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.id); // an alphanumeric id...
 });
```

**Server Side**

```
 const io = require('socket.io')().listen(portNumber);
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(socket.id); // same respective alphanumeric id...
 }
```

Comment: after reconnection `socket.id` will be still the same? In socket.io 2.x.x

Comment: No. It's not going to be the same. You need to find it again.

Answer (score 6):

The following code gives socket.id on client side.

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('connect', function(){
var id = socket.io.engine.id;
  alert(id);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

***To get client side socket id for Latest socket.io 2.0 use the code below***

```
 let socket = io(); 
 //on connect Event 
 socket.on('connect', () => {
     //get the id from socket
     console.log(socket.id);
 });
```