# How to make enemies look different than hero canvas socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, canvas, socket.io

Hello I am trying to create a Node.JS Socket.io Express browser game. I already have the basics ready, like making a new player instance when we join the localhost and making the player move correctly. The screen of the player is the full portion of the canvas (You always see everything), and there are borders preventing you from escaping.

The thing is whenever a user spawns, they are rendered Green. I want to make the user look green to the person whose controlling the user. I want to make everyone else red to indicate they are enemies.

So, whoever connected to the game must be green and everyone else red. (Almost like [diep.io](https://diep.io)).
I do recommend you check that game out as it is exactly what I'm looking for.

If you are wondering, here is the code (it is a bit messy)

Server Side (server.js):

```js
// Dependencies.
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
//
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
app.set('port', 5000);
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// Routing
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

server.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
  console.log('Starting server on port 5000');
});

//Interesting stuff
var players = {};
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('new player', function () {
    players[socket.id] = {
      x: 300,
      y: 300
    };
  });
  socket.on('movement', function (data) {
    var player = players[socket.id] || {};
    if (data.left && player.x >= 25) {
      player.x -= 5;
    }
    if (data.up && player.y >= 25) {
      player.y -= 5;
    }
    if (data.right && player.x <= 775) {
      player.x += 5;
    }
    if (data.down && player.y <= 575) {
      player.y += 5;
    }
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    players[socket.id] = {}
  })
});

setInterval(function () {
  io.sockets.emit('state', players);
}, 1000 / 60);
```

Client Side (game.js):

```js
var socket = io();

var movement = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 65: // A
      movement.left = true;
      break;
    case 87: // W
      movement.up = true;
      break;
    case 68: // D
      movement.right = true;
      break;
    case 83: // S
      movement.down = true;
      break;
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 65: // A
      movement.left = false;
      break;
    case 87: // W
      movement.up = false;
      break;
    case 68: // D
      movement.right = false;
      break;
    case 83: // S
      movement.down = false;
      break;
  }
});

socket.emit('new player');
setInterval(function () {
  socket.emit('movement', movement);
}, 1000 / 60);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
socket.emit('canvas', 800, 600);
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
socket.on('state', function (players) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
  //Get yourself
  for (var id in players) {
    var yourself = players[socketid];
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(yourself.x, yourself.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
  }
  //Get other players
  for (var id in players) {
    //Every player in the connection
    var player = players[id];
    //Draw each player on canvas
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(player.x, player.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
  }

});
```

index.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Multiplayer Game</title>
    <style>
      canvas {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="return false"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script src="/static/game.js"></script>
</html>
```

Visual Display Of Workspace:

```
|-server.js
|-index.html
|-static
  |-game.js
```

(Not showing files created by Node.JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to know your `socket.id`.

You can get your socket id when you connect:

```
let socket = io.connect('..'); 
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.id); // an alphanumeric id...
    //store the socket id
});
```

Then in your `state` event you can just make an if clause:

```
socket.on('state', function (players) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

  //Get other players
  for (var id in players) {
    //Every player in the connection
    var player = players[id];
    //Draw each player on canvas
    context.fillStyle = (id === <your_stored_socket.id or socket.id>)?'green':'red';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(player.x, player.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
  }

});
```

this should work just fine, for other details regarding how to get your socket id on client side you can refer here: [how to get socket.id of a connection on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270239/how-to-get-socket-id-of-a-connection-on-client-side)

Comment: Thank you very much! I started socket.io yesterday and this was just what I was looking for!